# Python Number to Word e.g 10K, 10.65M

Tags: python, django, humanize

I've looked into a few ways of representing numbers in a small space (in Django) and whilst their **django.contrib.humanize.intword** works great, i'd prefer if it said M instead of million for example. I know this wouldn't work with exceptionally large numbers (10^15 and 10^18 both start with Q).

I basically need four different unit names up to trillion: K, M, B and T. Are there any packages that allow a lot of configuration with numbers?

I've not posted any code because what I have works but not quite how i'd like it, this is just a question to see if there is a better way to get the numbers i'm hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to edit the code in humanize.intword on your local machine.  If I were doing this I would make a copy of the code and rename it.  Make adjustments as you need them and call the renamed version.  The source should be on your machine [humanize.intword](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py)

So something like (original)

```
(6, lambda number: (
    ungettext('%(value).1f million', '%(value).1f million', number),
    ungettext('%(value)s million', '%(value)s million', number),
)),
```

Change to the representation you need